# NumericUpDown Extender Does Not Stay Anchored

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ajax NumericUpDown extender like so:

```
<div style="float: left;">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFixedCost" runat="server" CssClass="app_textbox" Width="100px"
          Height="15px" Text="40" MaxLength="2" />
     <asp:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFixedCost"
          Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Width="50" />
</div>
```

The problem is that the textbox/extender controls do not stay anchored on the page when it scrolls. They move along with the scrolling. How can I get these controls to stay put? Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` style for the outer div